# How to call PHP preprocesser

Tags: php

I have written a web server that servers html,js,css,images etc using C. I want to develop it that it has the capability to server PHP content also.

In that case I think I want to pass the PHP content to PHP preprocesser dynamically. How to call the PHP preprocesser.( I am using Ubuntu)

Comment: Can you just call the php command and pass the string? It should give whatever it's echoed. Though you have to consider things like `header()`

Comment: There's a preprocessor for PHP?

Comment: @delnan: PHP stands for PHP Hypertext Preprocessor. PHP *is* the preprocessor.

Comment: You could check how Apache does it and copy the idea. They have a shared object associated with .php files that passes the processing of .php files to the php which returns the html it generates. Source is available, and if you're proficient enough with C - you should be able to get the concepts out of it.

Comment: @Tomalak: I know that acronym. But `php.exe` is simply an interpreter (or, more precisely, a bytecode compiler and bytecode interpreter), without a preprocessor. One might say a PHP script preprocesses HTML pages, but that's not relevant here.

Comment: @delnan: It's completely relevant, because that's what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, perhaps I'm misreading the question, but as far as I can tell, OP is talking about a preprocessor for PHP. And yeah, that's terminology nitpicking.

Comment: @delnan: He's describing PHP as a preprocessor. He wants to invoke it for use in his home-made web server, in order to "preprocess" HTML via PHP before display to an end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could process the PHP file through the command line functions.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

I believe you would do; `php -f <file>`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to invoke the **PHP-CGI binary** and communicate with that. Here is an example implementation in PHP, but it's quite simple in C as well:

- http://nanoweb-instant.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/modules/mod_cgi.php (advisable)
- http://nanoweb-instant.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/modules/mod_fcgi.php (avoid)

FastCGI is indeed faster, but is a fugly procotol. So I would recommend to avoid it. (SCGI is nicer, but not available for PHP).
If you really must, then look into http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5 for a readymade C-library for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to implement the FastCGI protocol. PHP can be run as FastCGI, as well as other scripting languages. This makes it possible to have PHP processes running as daemons, which speeds up page access times compared to traditional CGI and commandline calls.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way to do this is to implement CGI or FastCGI, which PHP both supports

Answer (score 1):

You could communicate with the PHP interpreter through FastCGI. This should perform better than calling php for each request.